# To not autoremove something

Tags: debian, apt

I have uninstalled my distro's (Debian Wheezy) package of torchat, and use a newer version I've built myself. Since removing the package apt-get wants me to autoremove something which the software I've built still depends on. How do I make it so I never see this warning again?

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
   python-socksipy
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work but you could try removing it and then reinstalling it manually. That way apt-get will no longer treat it as auto installed.

Comment: @terdon The removal step is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to build your package with the correct dependencies. As a quick hack you can mark the package as manually installed, this will prevent `autoremove` from removing it.

```
apt-mark manual python-socksipy
```

Comment: `apt-get install python-socksipy` would also work (but may try to upgrade in the process)